# What efforts have been made to convince UK nurses etc to get vaccinated?

Tags: united-kingdom, covid-19, vaccine

The Guardian reports that "nursing and midwifery leaders" have called to delay the Covid vaccination for everyone working in a health setting in the UK to avoid people being dismissed from next month onwards ([link](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2022/jan/12/sajid-javid-urged-to-delay-mandatory-jabs-for-nhs-staff-in-england)). Instead, they ask for more time to convince people to get vaccinated.

It seems to me that hospitals/nursing homes/etc should have been working on convincing their vaccine-hestitant staff they want to keep for at least half a year now. If they have indeed done so, I'd find it hard to imagine that anyone who is still willing to lose their job over this is still redeemable. On the other hand, this might just be a massive leadership failure if no education/persuasion measures have been running all this time.

So I'm interested in how widespread targeted efforts by hospitals/nursing homes/etc to get their own staff vaccinated are, how well they've been working, and if applicable, if there is any reason to hope that holdouts are still reachable.

Answer (score 2):

(Note that the mandatory vaccine for Health and Social care is a devolved matter, currently it only applies in England, and not in the other nations of the UK)

The most significant attempt to convince English nurses and midwives to get vaccinated is the decision that it would be dismissed if they didn't. That is a strong-arm tactic. It makes the negatives of not getting vaccinated much greater.

And surely, in wards up and down the England, senior nurses and hospital trust management have been trying to convince the few nurses that haven't had a covid vaccination to get one. The overwhelming majority of Heath care workers will have had three COVID jabs, and many will also have had a flu vaccine.

The RCN (the nurses union) [calls for](https://www.rcn.org.uk/about-us/our-influencing-work/position-statements/rcn-position-on-mandating-vaccination-for-health-and-social-care-staff)

> - Ensuring staff have easy access to the vaccines they need within the working day.
> - Providing staff with access to clear information about the risks and how to overcome or manage those risks, as well as information about the value and benefits of vaccination.
> - Providing confidential support to staff who have any vaccine related concerns

These are the efforts that have been made to "convince" English nurses to get vaccinated.

You are right that a Health care worker who has not yet been vaccinated must surely have a deeply held religious or philosophical objection, or a significant fear, bordering on phobia, and it is doubtful how many of the unvaccinated will choose vaccination in the light of deeply held beliefs.  It would be speculation to ask if they are "reachable".